# In Symfony Form class get the value of submitted fields

Tags: php

In symfony how I will get the value of $_REQUEST in a form class. I am getting the value of all form fields in **action.class.php** and templates. While submitting a form and it is validating I need to get the value of some form field. Please help me!

Comment: Please elaborate further on what you're having problems with - passing variables to the form for validation? or retrieving a field value before/after validation?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a value from a form after it's been bound and validated etc:

```
$value = $myForm->getValue("field_name");
```

If you want it before you pass it to the form:

```
public function executeMyAction(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $myForm = new MyForm();
  $allFormValues = $request->getParameter($myForm->getName());
  $value = $allFormValues["field_name"];

  // usual form stuff follows eg:
  $myForm->bind($allFormValues);

  // ...
}
```

If you want it eg in a postvalidator method in your form's validation schema:

```
public function myPostValidate($validator, $values)
{
  $myValue = $values["field_name"];

  // ...

  return $values;
}
```

Anything else, please expand your question and provide more detail as to what you're trying to do :-)

Answer (score -2):

How about using this?:

`sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getAttribute('your_widget_field_name');`

Comment: That assumes the value has been stored in the user's session; such storage depends on the existing logic written by the developer, it's not automatic.